# Creating a single bar chart from 2 seperate bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to merge 2 bar graphs from 2 different data sets I've created. In a was that would look similar when you would use the "position = "dodge" ". Not sure if this is possible, but please let me know. I essentially have to charts shown below, and i would also like to distinguish them with the colour aesthetic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
```

Creating some data.

```
df1 <- data.frame(CAT = LETTERS[1:5], vals = rnorm(5, 100))
df2 <- data.frame(CAT = LETTERS[1:5], vals = seq(20, 100, 17))
```

Add a variable that differentiates the two data frames:

```
df1$group <- "A"
df2$group <- "B"
```

And merge them:

```
merged_df <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

And chart:

```
ggplot(merged_df, aes(x = CAT, y = vals, fill = group)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]